# Django shell keeps losing connection to DB

Tags: django, postgresql

Django (or postgresql) keeps losing connection from `manage.py shell`.

I've been trying to google but couldn't find an answer.

Is there a change to Django2.0+ or postgresql10.0+ ?

Comment: Which versions specifically?

Comment: Django==2.0.13  PostgreSQL 10.9 @jmunsch

Comment: How long does it take for a lost connection?  Are we talking seconds, minutes, or hours?

Comment: several hours I think @JohnGordon